# How to set global.TextDecoder in jest for jsdom if node's util.TextDecoder is type mismatch?

Tags: angular, jestjs, jsdom

Try to use jsdom with Jest in an NX repo (typescript/angular) and I get the problem that `TextEncoder` and `TextDecoder` are not present. I get the same result whether I set the jest `testEnvironment` to `'jsdom'` or `'node'` and with versions of node from 10 to 16)

So, following solutions other people posted (thanks!), I imported them in my `test-setup.ts` from node and set them on the node global object:

```
import 'jest-preset-angular/setup-jest'
import { TextEncoder, TextDecoder } from 'util';

global.TextEncoder = TextEncoder;
global.TextDecoder = TextDecoder;
```

This seems to work for `TextEncoder`, but not for `TextDecoder`:

```
   libs/xplat/features/test-setup.ts:10:1 - error TS2322: Type 'typeof TextDecoder' is not assignable to type '{ new (label?: string | undefined, options?: TextDecoderOptions | undefined): TextDecoder; prototype: TextDecoder; }'.
      The types of 'prototype.decode' are incompatible between these types.
        Type '(input?: ArrayBufferView | ArrayBuffer | null | undefined, options?: { stream?: boolean | undefined; } | undefined) => string' is not assignable to type '(input?: BufferSource | undefined, options?: TextDecodeOptions | undefined) => string'.
          Types of parameters 'input' and 'input' are incompatible.
            Type 'BufferSource | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ArrayBufferView | ArrayBuffer | null | undefined'.
              Type 'ArrayBufferView' is not assignable to type 'ArrayBufferView | ArrayBuffer | null | undefined'.
                Type 'ArrayBufferView' is missing the following properties from type 'DataView': getFloat32, getFloat64, getInt8, getInt16, and 17 more.

    10 global.TextDecoder = TextDecoder;
```

Is there a different `TextDecoder` I should use - in particular, is there one somehow bundled with jest's jsdom which I'm just not seeing how to use?

In case it helps, here some versions (from my most recent `package.json`):

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.1301.2",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "<=13.0.2",
    ...
    "@nrwl/angular": "13.4.6",
    "@nrwl/cli": "13.4.6",
    ...
    "@nrwl/jest": "13.4.6",
     ...
    "@types/core-js": "^2.5.5",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.2",
    "@types/jsdom": "^16.2.14",
    "@types/node": "14.14.33",
    "@types/whatwg-url": "^8.2.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~5.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "~5.3.0",
   ...
    "jest": "27.2.3",
    "jest-jasmine2": "^27.4.6",
    "jest-preset-angular": "11.0.0",
    "jsdom": "^19.0.0",
    "ng-mocks": "^12.5.1",
    ...
    "ts-jest": "27.0.5",
    "typescript": "~4.4.3",
    "util": "^0.12.4",
    "whatwg-url": "^11.0.0"
  },
```

Answer (score 9):

I managed to get rid of the error by first coercing the global object to any then assigning the TextDecoder:

```
import { TextEncoder, TextDecoder } from "util";
(global as any).TextEncoder = TextEncoder;
(global as any).TextDecoder = TextDecoder;
```

I know it is not the best way of accomplishing the desired goal and would generally be considered bad practice but, as this is just for Jest's testing I think it should be ok.

Answer (score 3):

I where able to solve it by doing this:

```
import {TextDecoder as NodeTextDecoder} from 'util';

global.TextDecoder = NodeTextDecoder as typeof TextDecoder;
```

I think the problem comes from TextDecoder being a global Typescript type, therefor we need to use another name. I'm assertion a node TextDecoder to a TypeScript TextDecoder, I'm not sure if that is correct, but I think it is safer then any.

Comment: Thank God for you...this solved my problem after much research.